# Dropdown on DataViewGrid that writes back to SQL table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have two tables.

One Customer table and one Tarrif table.

I need to be able to get the user to select the Tarrif from a dropdown on the Customer DataGriView and for the selected value to be written back to the customer table.

Here is my code so for, it compiles and runs without errors - But the data is not being written back to the Customer table.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common

Public Class ViewCustomersForm
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Customer ID] ,[Customer Name] ,[Address] ,[City] ,[County] ,[Post Code] FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers]"
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)


Dim connStr2 As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=Test; integrated security=yes"
Dim sql2 As String = "SELECT * FROM Tarrifs"
Dim conn2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr2)
Dim comm2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql2, conn2)
Dim dataadapter2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm2)


Private Sub ViewCustomersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    '---open the connection and fill the Customer dataset---
    conn.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"

    'Tarrif Dropdown
    '---create a combobox column---
    Dim comboBoxCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    '---set the header---
    comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "Tarrifs"

    'Fill Tarrif Table
    dataadapter2.Fill(ds, "Tarrifs")

    '---data bind it--
    comboBoxCol.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tarrifs")
    comboBoxCol.DisplayMember = "Tarrif"
    comboBoxCol.ValueMember = "Tarrif"

    '---add a combobox column to the DataGridView control---
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxCol)


End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Save updated Customer DataGridView
    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))

    'Save updated Tarrif dropdown back to Customer table
    Dim sqlCmdBuilder2 As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter2)
    sqlCmdBuilder2.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter2.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))


End Sub

End Class
```

I am new to VB, can anyone help point in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what column of the Customers table are you expecting this Tariff data to be written to?  You don't appear to be retrieving any corresponding column so where is the data supposed to go?

Comment: That's what I am not sure how to do. It needs to go to a column called Tariff on my customer table. If anyone could point me in the right direction I will be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually retrieve the column that you want to populate, so that your `DataTable` then includes a column to populate and thus save back to the database.  You would then bind that column to your grid's combo box column via its `DataPropertyName`, just as all the other columns are bound.  Here's an example:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476-NET-2-0-Adding-a-ComboBox-Column-to-a-DataGridView&highlight=